# Regex to match all Romanian phone numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I searched the whole google to find some ways to verify if the phone number is Romanian but didn't found anything that helps me...
I want a Regex validator for the following numbers format:

```
074xxxxxxx
075xxxxxxx
076xxxxxxx
078xxxxxxx
072xxxxxxx
077xxxxxxx
0251xxxxxx
0351xxxxxx
```

This is the regex that I've made, but it is not working:

```
{ "Romania", new Regex("(/^(?:(?:(?:00\\s?|\\+)40\\s?|0)(?:7\\d{2}\\s?\\d{3}\\s?\\d{3}|(21|31)\\d{1}\\s?\\d{3}\\s?\\d{3}|((2|3)[3-7]\\d{1})\\s?\\d$)")}
```

It doesn't validate the correct numbers format.

More details:

- If the number begins with other than the initial ones that I've added, then that number is not valid.
- The x should contain any number, but there should not be the same number..like 0000000 1111111 etc.
- It can also have the following format (but not mandatory): (072)xxxxxxx

Is there any way of doing this?

I want to implement this to store these numbers in database and check if their format is Romanian.
This is the code where I need to add the regex expression...there should be a new Regex named "Romanian"

```
static IDictionary<string, Regex> countryRegex = new Dictionary<string, Regex>()
{
    { "USA", new Regex("^[2-9]\\d{2}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}$")},
    { "UK", new Regex("(^1300\\d{6}$)|(^1800|1900|1902\\d{6}$)|(^0[2|3|7|8]{1}[0-9]{8}$)|(^13\\d{4}$)|(^04\\d{2,3}\\d{6}$)")},
    { "Netherlands", new Regex("(^\\+[0-9]{2}|^\\+[0-9]{2}\\(0\\)|^\\(\\+[0-9]{2}\\)\\(0\\)|^00[0-9]{2}|^0)([0-9]{9}$|[0-9\\-\\s]{10}$)")},
};
```

Comment: Your definition isn't clear enough. Do the hard-coded prefixes you've provided need to be matched explicitly? Do you allow certain special characters? Are you trying to pull out just the numbers so you can store just those numbers in the database?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the description. It would be great if I can make it to allow '( )' and '-' to separate the numbers

Comment: Why use regex? You could just check the strings manually and save yourself all that pain. Regex isn't always the best solution.

Comment: Just to second what @MichaelPerrenoud said, we'd be happy to help you construct such a regular expression, but constructing a good regex requires knowledge about the rules of the pattern.  Since most of us aren't from Romania, you need to be very clear about all of the possible variations that should be considered matches.  A list of rules that describe what does and does not match and a list of examples which should and should not match would be required to make this a decent question.

Comment: I'm using a tutorial for an web application, and it is using regex

Comment: Please show the regex which you have written so far but that isn't working.

Comment: I have added extra details to the description

Comment: When you have literal `\ `'s in your string (as in `\d`), you must escape them by doubling (`"\\d"`) or use verbatim strings (`@"\d"`)

Comment: @HansKesting I've edited the code according to your proposal and the errors disappeared but the validator not validates a correct number

Comment: @PavelValeriu Thanks for updating your question with all the additional details.  That made it much more answerable.  I have provided an answer which works to the best understanding of what I think you need.  Let me know if I misunderstood something or if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the rules correctly, this pattern should work:

```
^(?<paren>\()?0(?:(?:72|74|75|76|77|78)(?(paren)\))(?<first>\d)(?!\k<first>{6})\d{6}|(?:251|351)(?(paren)\))(?<first>\d)(?!\k<first>{5})\d{5})$
```

So, you could add it to your code like this:

```
static IDictionary<string, Regex> countryRegex = new Dictionary<string, Regex>()
{
    { "USA", new Regex("^[2-9]\\d{2}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}$")},
    { "UK", new Regex("(^1300\\d{6}$)|(^1800|1900|1902\\d{6}$)|(^0[2|3|7|8]{1}[0-9]{8}$)|(^13\\d{4}$)|(^04\\d{2,3}\\d{6}$)")},
    { "Netherlands", new Regex("(^\\+[0-9]{2}|^\\+[0-9]{2}\\(0\\)|^\\(\\+[0-9]{2}\\)\\(0\\)|^00[0-9]{2}|^0)([0-9]{9}$|[0-9\\-\\s]{10}$)")},
    { "Romania", new RegEx(@"^(?<paren>\()?0(?:(?:72|74|75|76|77|78)(?(paren)\))(?<first>\d)(?!\k<first>{6})\d{6}|(?:251|351)(?(paren)\))(?<first>\d)(?!\k<first>{5})\d{5})$")}
};
```

Here is the meaning of the pattern:

- `^` - Matches must start at the beginning of the input string
- `(?<paren>\()?` - Optionally matches a `(` character.  If it is there, it captures it in a group named `paren`
- `0` - The number must start with a single `0`
- `(?:` - Begins an non-capturing group for the purpose of matching one of two different formats
- `(?:72|74|75|76|77|78)(?(paren)\))(?<first>\d)(?!\k<first>{6})\d{6}` - The first format

  - `(?:72|74|75|76|77|78)` - The next two digits must be `72`, `74`, `75`, `76`, `77`, or `78`
  - `(?(paren)\))` - If the opening `(` exists, then there must be a closing `)` here
  - `(?<first>\d)` - Matches just the first of the ending seven digits and captures it in a group named `first`
  - `(?!\k<first>{6})` - A negative look-ahead which ensures that the remaining six digits are not the same as the first one
  - `\d{6}` - Matches the remaining six digits
- `|` - The *or* operator
- `(?:251|351)(?(paren)\))(?<first>\d)(?!\k<first>{5})\d{5}` - The second format

  - `(?:251|351)` - The next three digits must be `251` or `351`.
  - `(?(paren)\))` - If the opening `(` exists, then there must be a closing `)` here
  - `(?<first>\d)` - Matches just the first of the ending six digits and captures it in a group named `first`
  - `(?!\k<first>{5})` - A negative look-ahead which ensures that the remaining five digits are not the same as the first one
  - `\d{5}` - Matches the remaining five digits
- `)` - Ends the non-capturing group which specified the two potential formats
- `$` - The match must go all the way to the of the input string

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you for additional information, now I can update this expression if I need other conditions

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: `^(?=0[723][2-8]\d{7})(?!.*(.)\1{2,}).{10}$` - The negative lookahead `(?!...)`  is testing the repeating characters

I use http://regexr.com/ to test

Answer (score -1):

This match your example:

```
0(([7][456728])|([23]51)).*
```

Comment: This doesn't check if the length is correct, nor if "there should not be the same number..like 0000000 1111111 etc."

Comment: @NewWorld when I posted the answer, it fitted the need... :/